# away3d shadow with pointlight

Tags: flash, actionscript, 3d, away3d

For my project, I need to display the shadow of objects on the ground (a plane), from a point light source.
The objects can be very close to the light source, and I need to display the shadow on long distance.

In order to calculate the shadow from a PointLight, I use `HardShadowMapMethod`.

My problem is:

Either I set light falloff with small value (or epsilon with high value) and a lot of parrallel lines are displayed on the ground (kind of artifact?)

Or I set light falloff with high value but there is a big shadow gap between the object and his shadow.

I use Gold version.

Playing with the parameters light radius, light falloff, epsilon and dephtmapsize, it is impossible to have a shadow without gap AND without parrallel lines.

Is there a solution for this kind of situation? 
is there other method than `HardShadowMapMethod` which support point light source?

Here is a screenshot :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to play with

- Light fallOff value
- Shadow epsilon
- Casting object size